# How to save logs into file with timestamp with log4j2

Tags: java, xml, logging, log4j2

i have a little problem. I had to change my logging implementation from org.apache.commons.logging to org.apache.logging.log4j. I saved my logs into a "log" directory and each file got a appended timestamp. 
I used the following .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>

   <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="INFO"/>

   <timestamp key="myTimestamp" timeReference="contextBirth" datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd'_'HH-mm-ss"/>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}  - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/logs/app-${myTimestamp}.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>app.%i{yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS}}.log</FileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>30MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com....." level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Now i wanted to extend my xml file with log4j2, because of some new environments. But i also want to save it in the "logs" directory again. I tried different methods via the documentation and http://www.baeldung.com, but i don't get. My application always writes in the my app.log again without timestamp. How can i realize it? Where is the mistake in my new .xml ? 
I thought with this

```
filePattern="logs/ldapmicroservice.%d{MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm}.log.gz"
```

i define the new pattern of my file?
This is my new .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30"

    packages="com......">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p %X{mdcData} --- %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n%ex
        </Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders> 
        <RollingFile 
            name="FILE" fileName="/logs/app.log" 
            filePattern="logs/app.%d{MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm}.log.gz"
            ignoreExceptions="false">
                <PatternLayout>
                    <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %p %m%n</Pattern>
                </PatternLayout>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        </RollingFile> 

        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
        </Console>  
        <CloudantAppender name="CloudantAppender" 
            database="logs"
            ......
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
        </CloudantAppender>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com...." level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE" />
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
            <AppenderRef ref="CloudantAppender" />
        </Logger>

        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE" />
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
            <AppenderRef ref="CloudantAppender" />  
        </Root>

    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: ok, i found the solution by myself, the origin post is updated

Comment: Rather than updating your question, I would recommend posting a self-answer (just post an answer and accept it yourself) to notify to other users that your question is solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution on my own:

```
<RollingFile 
    name="FILE" fileName="/logs/app-${date:yyyy-MM-dd'_'HH-mm-ss}.log" 
    filePattern="logs/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log"
    ignoreExceptions="false">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd'_'HH-mm-ss} %p %m%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
</RollingFile>
```